# How to migrate azure resources from one directory to another directory

Tags: azure

I have requirements to move all the resources (vNet,subnet, VM, Storage etc) from existing directory to new directory and new subscription. all the subscriptions are managed by CSP

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Per our [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources), you will need to contact support since you are looking to move these resources to a new AAD tenant.

**When to call support**

You can move most resources through the self-service operations shown in this article. Use the self-service operations to:

- Move Resource Manager resources.
- Move classic resources according to
  the classic deployment limitations.

Contact support when you need to:

- Move your resources to a new Azure account (and Azure Active Directory tenant) and you need help with the instructions in the preceding section.
- Move classic resources but are having trouble with the limitations.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources